how to create a template with both default type argument and variadic type argument? or any work around
I created a trait struct FnOnArg to see if Fn can call on Arg
template<typename Fn, typename Arg, typename=void>
struct FnOnArg: std::false_type {};

template<typename Fn, typename Arg>
struct FnOnArg<Fn, Arg, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Fn>()(std::declval<Arg>()))>>: std::true_type {};

It can only work on Fn with one argument
I want to create FnOnArgs like
template<typename Fn, typename... Args, typename=void>
struct FnOnArgs;

but variadic and default template argument both should be the last argument
Any workaround to achieve FnOnArgs?

Why not just use std::is_invocable?

How to check at compile-time if a function that can be called with a specific set of arguments exists?

With C++20, you might use requires and concept

You move the dummy template argument typename = void to have it somewhere before typename... Args.
This means it can no longer have the default argument (= void), so you remove it and pass void explicitly.
You then create another template that wraps this one and adds void automatically, so you don't have to pass it every time.
template <typename Void, typename Fn, typename ...Args>
struct FnOnArgsLow : std::false_type {};

template <typename Fn, typename ...Args>
struct FnOnArgsLow<std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Fn>()(std::declval<Args>()...))>, Fn, Args...> : std::true_type {};

// The wrapper can be a variable or a class, whatever you like more.
template <typename Fn, typename ...Args>
static constexpr bool FnOnArgs = FnOnArgsLow<void, Fn, Args...>::value;


It is not possible to have a default template parameter after a parameter pack.
A possible solution may be the use of a wrapper structure, which allows to pack the variadic number of parameters and then pass it as a single argument. In this case, std::tuple has been used for simplicity.
Example:
namespace detail {
  template<typename, typename, typename = void>
  struct FnOnArg
   : std::false_type {};

  template<typename Fn, typename ...Args>
  struct FnOnArg<Fn, std::tuple<Args...>, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Fn>()(std::declval<Args...>()))>>
   : std::true_type {};
}

template <typename Fn, typename ...Args>
struct FnOnArg
 : detail::FnOnArg<Fn, std::tuple<Args...>> {};


Using a tuple for this is an overkill. I'm worried about the compilation time overhead a bit. At least I'd create my own type list class.

Just change the placement of the template parameters as shown below:
template<typename Fn, typename=void, typename... Arg>
struct FnOnArg: std::false_type {};

template<typename Fn, typename... Arg>
struct FnOnArg<Fn, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Fn>()(std::declval<Arg>()...))>, Arg...>: std::true_type {};

//making an alias 
template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
constexpr static bool FnOnArg_v = FnOnArg<Fn, void, Args...>::value;


Working demo

@HolyBlackCat Updated.
